# Error when creating restful controller test with xml

Tags: xml, rest, spring-boot, spring-web

I'm trying to create a controller test with payload in xml, using MockMvc,
But when I run the test the following error appears:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; [Fatal Error]: 1: 1: Premature end of file.
```

My test method

```
@Test
public void newTransaction() throws Exception {

    String payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
            + "<Transaction>"
                + "<transAmt>20059</transAmt>"
                + "<merchId>687555537877464</merchId>"
                + "<merchNameLoc>Best</merchNameLoc>"
                + "<transDate>12312010</transDate>"
                + "<retCd>0</retCd>"
            + "</Transaction>";

    mockMvc.perform(post("/rtm/transaction")
            .content(payload)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
            .andExpect(xpath("//transactionId").exists())
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

And my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transaction", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Transaction> newTransaction(@RequestBody NotificationCommand command){
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value for this MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE ? Is it same as application/xml ?

Comment: The type of consumer is not important, so I even removed it. sry

Comment: hey guys i find the error, i was in the line
   
    .andExpect(xpath("//transactionId").exists())

where xpath could not find the value transactionId.